# Shadow effect using CSS

Tags: css

I need to implement shadow effect as below attached mockup. I have highlighted the shadow effect that I need to implement as red box. I have been told to use the sprite image to implement this shadow effect which I don't like. Can I use CSS3 shadow effect to implement this?

[image]

Please advice

Comment: Have a look at this https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/

Comment: **Yes** you can use `CSS3` for this. We can advice you more if can show your effort.

Comment: http://cssdeck.com/labs/different-css3-box-shadows-effects ? Learn to Google first, always...

Comment: @Akshay and how that helps him solve the issue? it's not thaat easy to get that effect by just using a simple `box-shadow`

Comment: A few ways you can try for example using `box-shadow`, `background-gradient`

Comment: @Mr.Alien Did you look at it ? The last part shows a codepen that contains the effect he is looking for

Comment: @Akshay He just updated his almanac... used to only contain docs like definitions before.. my bad..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```css
hr {
height: 1px;
margin: 50px 0;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(0.5, #333333), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), #333333, rgba(0,0,0,0));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), #333333, rgba(0,0,0,0));
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), #333333, rgba(0,0,0,0));
background: linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), #333333, rgba(0,0,0,0));
border: 0;
}

hr:after { 
display: block; 
content:'';
height: 30px;
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 0%, 0, 50% 0%, 116, color-stop(0%, #cccccc), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center top, farthest-side, #cccccc 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center top, farthest-side, #cccccc 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
background: -o-radial-gradient(center top, farthest-side, #cccccc 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
background: radial-gradient(farthest-side at center top, #cccccc 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing sample. I think I can make changes to meet my goal.

Comment: btw...how to learn these deep level of css syntax. I am not new to CSS, but always feel difficult to write complex css :-(